# JFace TableViewer - Setting font color for all Cells in table

Tags: java, fonts, swt, jface

I have asked a very similar question, but I ended up using images instead of changing the color.

I want all the text in the cells to be dark grey.  I understand that you have to assign each column.  But I do not how to do it.

This is one of my columns in my TableViewer.

```
col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
col.getColumn().setWidth(200);
col.getColumn().setText("Printer/Profile");
col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData p = (AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) element;
        return p.getPrinterProfile();
    }
});
```

How would I change the above code to incorporate setting the font color to dark gray?

**EDIT**

If I am using the switch, how does it know how many columns I have?
also how do I set the column names?  Here is how I have it set up right now

```
TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(this , SWT.NONE);
  col.getColumn().setWidth(150);
  col.getColumn().setText("ItemId");
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
     @Override
     public void update(ViewerCell cell)
     {
         Object element = cell.getElement();
         if(element instanceof AplotPDFDataModel.FileNameData)
         {
            AplotPDFDataModel.FileNameData p = (AplotPDFDataModel.FileNameData) element;
            cell.setForeground(ColorConstants.darkGray);
            switch(cell.getColumnIndex())
            {
               case 0:
                  try {
                     cell.setText(p.getRev().getStringProperty("item_id"));
                  }
                  catch (TCException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  break;
               case 1:
                  try {
                     cell.setText(p.getRev().getStringProperty("item_revision_id"));
                  }
                  catch (TCException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  break;
               case 2:
                  cell.setText(p.getPRLValue().toString());
                  break;
               case 3:
                  cell.setText(p.getMarkupValue());
                  break;
               case 4:
                  cell.setText(p.getFileName());
                  break;
             }
         }
     }
 });
```

Comment: Well, you do know, how many columns your table has, don't you? What do you mean by: "_how do I set the column names_"? Maybe my alternative solution would be the better choice for you, since it involves less code changes.

Comment: I mean column titles and column widths.  I really want to learn how to use the Switch.  Example would be column 1 title should be itemID with a width of 100 and column 2 title should be revId with a width of 50

Comment: Moreover, if you use the first alternative, just create a new class for the `ColumnLabelProvider` and use `col.setLabelProvider(new YourColumnLabelProvider())`. This will decrease redundant code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the method [`update(ViewerCell cell)`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ColumnLabelProvider.html#update%28org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell%29) of the `ColumnLabelProvider` instead of `getText()`. Then you can call [`ViewerCell#setForeground(Color color)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ViewerCell.html#getForeground%28%29):

```
public class ColorColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider {
    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell)
    {
        Object element = cell.getElement();
        if(element instanceof AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData)
        {
            AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData p = (AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) element;

            cell.setForeground(YOUR_COLOR);
            switch(cell.getColumnIndex())
            {
                case 0:
                    cell.setText(p.YOUR_FIRST_TEXT);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.setText(p.YOUR_SECOND_TEXT);
                    break;
                case ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then use:

```
col.getColumn().setWidth(150);
col.getColumn().setText("ItemId");
col.setLabelProvider(new ColorColumnLabelProvider());
```

Since I `switch` the column index, you can use this `ColorColumnLabelProvider` for all your columns.

Don't forget to dispose the color somewhere.

If you use [`ColorConstants`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/draw2d/ColorConstants.html) of [Draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php), you don't need to dispose them.

In your case [`ColorConstants.darkGray`](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/topic/org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/draw2d/ColorConstants.html#darkGray) would do the job.

**ALTERNATIVE**:

You can also define a `ColumnLabelProvider` that implements [`IColorProvider`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FIColorProvider.html):

```
public class ColorColumnLabelProvider extends ColumnLabelProvider implements IColorProvider {

    @Override
    public Color getBackground(Object element) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Color getForeground(Object element) {
        return YOUR_COLOR;
    }

    @Override
    public String getText(Object element) {
        AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData p = (AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) element;
        return p.getPrinterProfile();
    }

}
```

Comment: I am having a issue with ColorConstants.darkGray.  It wants me to import java.swing.text.StyleConstants.  I can not use Swing only SWT.  Can ColorConstants still be used?

Comment: @jkteater You have to add the Draw2d jar to your project in order to use `ColorConstants`. Or install Draw2d via the software manager. You can however use the SWT colors. But then you have to dispose them somewhere.

Comment: I added Draw2d to my required plugins, it seemed to help - still need to test

Comment: If I use a system color - Color dGray = Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY);  Do I have to dispose it?

Comment: @jkteater No, you don't have to dispose colors you get using this method. In fact you mustn't dispose it.