# How can we change text of a table row in swt using jface

Tags: java, swt, jface

I need to change the text of the table item when  messages are displayed in the tableitem .so how can we do it using jface .The table consists of 2 coloumns.Please help to resolve this as i am new to jface .

Comment: What do you mean with "text" and "messages"? Are you using a `Table` or a `TableViewer`?

Comment: i am using a table.Here text and messages are same which means any text.It is better if you give the idea using tableviewer as it uses jface

Comment: So do you want to use a table or a tableviewer? And please explain in more detail what you want to achieve. I still don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: I want to use table viewer where i need to create a table which updates the second coloumn with a text and the text colour has to be changing like red ,blue etc

Comment: And what exactly are you struggling with?

Comment: Actuaaly i need to change the text colour in  the table items

Comment: Have a look at the [answer I posted here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12821571/1740724). You can easily change the text color based on the text with the code I provided.

Comment: Can you provide me an sample of creating a table using tableviewer with 2 coloumns and 10 rows

Comment: I could, but you'd definitely benefit more from doing it yourself. However, [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJFaceTable/article.html) is an excellent tutorial that should help you in the process.

Comment: I am trying to create from past 2 hours but lot of errors so please help me in creating a table using tableviewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a very basic example. You'll have to handle the mapping between `String` representation of colors and the actual `Color`s yourself:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> COLOR_MAPPING = new HashMap<>();

static
{
    COLOR_MAPPING.put("red", SWT.COLOR_RED);
    COLOR_MAPPING.put("blue", SWT.COLOR_BLUE);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);

    createColumns(viewer);

    final Table table = viewer.getTable();
    table.setHeaderVisible(true);
    table.setLinesVisible(true);

    List<MyObject> data = new ArrayList<>();
    data.add(new MyObject("Something", "red"));
    data.add(new MyObject("Something else", "blue"));
    data.add(new MyObject("Something else entirely", "bleen"));

    viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());
    viewer.setInput(data);

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();

    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
        {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}

private static void createColumns(TableViewer viewer)
{
    TableViewerColumn first = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    first.getColumn().setWidth(200);
    first.getColumn().setText("First");
    first.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell)
        {
            Object element = cell.getElement();
            if(element instanceof MyObject)
            {
                MyObject obj = (MyObject) element;
                cell.setText(obj.getFirst());
            }
        }
    });

    TableViewerColumn second = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
    second.getColumn().setWidth(200);
    second.getColumn().setText("Second");
    second.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider()
    {
        @Override
        public void update(ViewerCell cell)
        {
            Object element = cell.getElement();
            if(element instanceof MyObject)
            {
                MyObject obj = (MyObject) element;

                cell.setText(obj.getSecond());

                Integer colorCode = COLOR_MAPPING.get(obj.getSecond());

                if(colorCode != null)
                        cell.setForeground(Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(colorCode));
            }
        }
    });
}

private static class MyObject
{
    private String first;
    private String second;

    public MyObject(String first, String second)
    {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public String getFirst()
    {
        return first;
    }

    public void setFirst(String first)
    {
        this.first = first;
    }

    public String getSecond()
    {
        return second;
    }

    public void setSecond(String second)
    {
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]